# My faith in a Senior role has vanished

Tags: job-offer, new-job, job-change

I joined a company a month ago and we were just two: My manager with me as a Designer. Prior to joining, I asked for a Senior role and I was told that, "We will discuss this when we will expand the team."  Today, a new designer joined as a Senior - but I wasn't told that he'd be joining as a Senior.

I feel angry because this means that becoming a Senior is out of the question unless the new guy leaves. Even if I get promoted, I do not think it makes sense to have two senior designers. It is like having two captains on one ship.

Am I making a fuss for nothing?  I am considering leaving the company, even though I am happy at the workplace. Please note that in my previous job, I was a Senior already.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want us to help you with?

Comment: Are you being well paid?  Other than the title, is anything wrong?

Comment: I feel bad because in my previous job, I was a Senior already and also was Leading an important project for the whole company having 32 brands..... What I feel bad about is that I wasnt told that a Senior was already joining. I was promised that I had a chance to become a senior in the future, but how that could happen, if a Senior already joined? Its funny.

Comment: Nothing about having another senior joining stops you becoming one. Did you have commitment as to timelines on you getting a title change?

Comment: @RoryAlsop nope.... was just told that in the future when the team grows, we discuss it...... but as I said... if a Senior just joined, even if the team grows, it doesnt make sense to have two seniors... I feel that I was taken for a ride just to accept the job.

Comment: I have grown teams that ended up with numerous "seniors" - it's just a title. It isn't the top position in any org.

Comment: I think you may be confusing "senior" with "lead". Any large project can benefit from multiple seniors, but multiple leads will cause confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Junior, senior etc are just indications of experience levels, not authority. How these levels are scaled, sadly, are based on the company and their perception of these levels.

I would most certainly not feel intimidated by this new hire and just do your best to prove you deserve that title and possibly higher pay grade.

Comment: I feel bad because in my previous job, I was a Senior already and also was Leading an important project for the whole company having 32 brands..... What I feel bad about is that I wasnt told that a Senior was already joining. I was promised that I had a chance to become a senior in the future, but how that could happen, if a Senior already joined? Its funny.

Comment: Then you should have negotiated better, sorry to be blunt.

Comment: A Senior in one company might be an Intermediate in another, with identical skill expectations. It's just a title and there is no universal definition of Senior Something.